# jenkins-specific log4j error in multi-module maven2/3 project

Tags: maven, jenkins, log4j, maven-surefire-plugin

I have [a project](https://evolvis.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=kolab-ws/kolab-ws.git;a=summary) which contains a parent POM and four subdirectories. The parent directory doesn’t built any code; three subdirectories build code, the fourth builds an EAR out of them. One of the subdirectories (`kolab-ws`) contains the unit tests. The top-level does not contain *any* code or `src` subdirectory (although the repository contains three more subdirectories, these are not connected to the top-level `pom.xml`), and we build this from *one* Jenkins job, not several, as the separation is cosmetic (for easier maintenance), not due to modularisation.

I got a number of warnings…

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

… in the logs, and [fixed](https://evolvis.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=kolab-ws/kolab-ws.git;a=commit;h=3c8cfae91c5645ba03e14516eb10368b96220b00) that by adding `kolab-ws/src/test/resources/log4j.properties`, however, one such warning remains:

```
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.03 sec - in org.evolvis.xml.util.DateTypeAdapterTest

Results :

Tests run: 30, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[JENKINS] Recording test results
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.commons.beanutils.converters.BooleanConverter).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

That is, the warning happens *immediately* after the `[JENKINS] Recording test results` message, and it *does **not*** happen when I build the project on the command line (`mvn -e clean package`, which is what is configured in Jenkins), logged in as jenkins user on the jenkins server, in the same workspace it occurred before when building via the CI.

So far, I’ve been unable to fing out what this “recording test results” is about or rather, what commands it runs (for manually reproducing things); I’ve looked at the Jenkins JUnit and Maven plugins, and [played with surefire-plugin settings](https://evolvis.org/plugins/scmgit/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=kolab-ws/kolab-ws.git;a=commitdiff;h=f20db5907c2c714fe5b9ca66f9eb34ef47400d50;hp=ef670438dfe9d20146b8d9e27b076801f91bb1fd) but haven’t had any success in removing this warning. Since my usual policy is to have no warnings during the build (or run) I wish to silence it (not by disabling logging but by fixing the underlying problem, of course).

Comment: did you try to run it with -X switch to get more information?

Comment: @KirilS. what exactly? If I just run maven, I do not get the error. This is some internal Jenkins magic.